# Learning typescript: TS2349: This expression is not callable. Type 'never' has no call signatures

Tags: typescript

I am learning typescript and at the moment, I am trying to implement it on an existing vue3-project.

Given this old mixin-method:

```
export const promises = {

    methods: {
        async process(...args): Promise<unknown> {
            return await Promise.all(args.map(async (arg) => {
                return await this.getResult(arg);
            }));
        },
    }
};
```

I am getting this error when I am calling the process-method from another component:

> TS2349: This expression is not callable.   Type 'never' has no call signatures.

I do not understand: Why is typescript referring to type `never` here? And how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but I don't think that you should use `await` into the body of the inner `map` method, since `Promise.all` accepts an array of promises. This way you are passing to `Promise.all` an array of _whatever is the type of the promise returned by `getResults`_. I think `Promise.all(args.map(arg =>  this.getResult(arg) ))` is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Mixins in TS can only infer information they are given. You cannot infer information which is not explicitly given, esp. relevant with the mixin pattern, where it is only combined at the end. As such we can utilize a lot of TS features to help us with the mixin pattern. See the recommended method at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

I went ahead and changed `this.methods.process` or `this.methods.getResult` just to direct methods, as it is easier to do with this pattern.

```js
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => {};
type GConstructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class MyBase {
  constructor() {}
  async getResult(a: any) {return a}
}

type MyBaseable = GConstructor<MyBase>

function Promises<TBase extends MyBaseable>(Base: TBase) {
  return class PromiseClass extends Base {
    async process (...args: any[]): Promise<unknown> {
        return await Promise.all(args.map(async (arg) => {
            return await this.getResult(arg);
        }));
    }
  };
}

const Mixer = Promises(MyBase);

(async () => {
  const myInstance = new Mixer()
  const _ = await myInstance.process('a', 'b', 'c')
})()
```

Alternatively if you want to keep `this.methods` you can do something like this:

```js
class MyBase {
  // Use private members
  _baseMethods = {
    getResult: async (a: any) => {return a}
  }

  constructor() {}
}

type MyBaseable = GConstructor<MyBase>

function Promises<TBase extends MyBaseable>(Base: TBase) {
  return class PromiseClass extends Base {
    // Merge in the most outer-mixin as members
    methods = {
      ...this._baseMethods,
      process: async (...args: any[]): Promise<unknown> => {
        return await Promise.all(args.map(async (arg) => {
            return await this._baseMethods.getResult(arg);
        }));
      }
    }
  };
}
```

View this on [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mb00dw)

Some more reading on TS mixins:

- [The mixin pattern in TypeScript – all you need to know](https://www.bryntum.com/blog/the-mixin-pattern-in-typescript-all-you-need-to-know/)
- [The Mixin Pattern In TypeScript – All You Need To Know Part 2](https://www.bryntum.com/blog/the-mixin-pattern-in-typescript-all-you-need-to-know-part-2/)